# Typo3 RSS Feed has no items

Tags: xml, typo3, rss, feed, tt-news

I've got a problem with the integration of a RSS feed on my website. I am working with the extension News System, which has the feature RSS Feed included.

On the list view of my news page I put in the following template (content from setup area). I've replaced paths and other sensible data with [...].

```
plugin.tx_news {
  view {
    templateRootPath = [...]
    partialRootPath = [...]
    layoutRootPath = [...]
  }

  settings.cssFile >
  skipControllerAndAction = 1
}

[globalVar = TSFE:type = 9818]
config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    xhtml_cleaning = none
    admPanel = 0
    debug = 0
    disablePrefixComment = 1
    metaCharset = utf-8
    additionalHeaders.10.header = Content-Type:application/rss+xml;charset=utf-8
    absRefPrefix = https://www.slawitscheck.at/bmw/news/
    linkVars >
}

pageNewsRSS = PAGE
pageNewsRSS {
    typeNum = 9818
    10 < tt_content.list.20.news_pi1
    10 {
            switchableControllerActions {
                    News {
                            1 = list
                    }
            }
            settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
            settings {
                    categories = 1
                    categoryConjunction = OR
                    limit = 30
                    detailPid = [...]
                    startingpoint = [...]
                    format = xml
                    list.rss.channel {
                      title = Slawitscheck BMW: RSS Feed
                      link = https://www.slawitscheck.at/bmw/news/
                      description = Ihr RSS Feed für alle News rund um die H. Slawitscheck GmbH. ► BMW, Mini, Neu- und Gebrauchtwägen, Service-Angebote und vieles mehr..
                      copyright = H. Slawitscheck GmbH
                      language = de-DE
                      generator = TYPO3 EXT:news
                      category = 1
                    }
            }
    }
}

[global]
```

detailPid is the ID of my news detail apge and the startingpoint is the ID of my News page. So https://www.slawitscheck.at/bmw/news/.

On this page only news with category 1 are shown, so that's why I put category 1 also in the setup. I only want category 1 news in my rss feed.

I edited the List.html so that I've got this link for the rss feed in the head of my page:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="/bmw/news/?type=9818">
```

Okay, so when I open the feed in a RSS reader (tried several different ones), the feed shows up as valid but it has no items! The feed is empty, althought there are news items with category 1.

**News are not Set. In the NewsController in listAction() the value for 'news' is always empty. For the RSS Feed but not for the News-Page.**

That's the link directly to the RSS feed: https://www.slawitscheck.at/bmw/news/?type=9818

The info I put in the template is set correctly, I just don't have any items. I didn't change the Typo3-Template for the RSS Feed (List.xml).

I already googled this, but unfortunately I can't find a solution for this problem.

### Edit

Here is a screenshot of the Tree from pageNewsRSS! :)

1:
[image]

2:
[image]

3:
[image]

Comment: Is category with uid 1 assigned to any news? How does the TS tree in the configuration module look like for `pageNewsRSS`? What is your `startingpoint` setting and are any news located there?

Comment: All the news on https://www.slawitscheck.at/bmw/news/ have category 1, so yes, there are many news assigned to that category.
The startingpoint is the ID of the page https://www.slawitscheck.at/bmw/news/.

What do you mean with TS tree? I posted the whole code I configured for pageNewsRSS.

That's the manual I worked by: https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/7.3/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Rss/Index.html

Comment: The TypoScript code you posted is just your config, but as you copy from TS objects with "<", there is some more in it in the end. With TS tree, I mean the tree you see, when using Web => Template => TypoScript Object Browser in the backend. Can you post a screenshot of the expanded tree for `pageNewsRSS`?

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the clarification. Didn't know about the feature! :) I added the screenshots to the original post.

Comment: Hm, the config seems ok. Without further knowledge of the structure of your site, it's hard to tell, sorry.

Comment: News are not Set. In the NewsController in listAction() the value for 'news' is always empty. For the RSS Feed but not for the News-Page.